# Magento 2: How to add a class of style to body tag?

Tags: magento2, template

Magento version: 2.0.0

How to add a class of style into  tag?
I think it is added in the xml, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's done via XML I reckon you can use the attribute tag for this

So in your layout, you can do:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-body-class" />
    <attribute name="id" value="my-html-id"/>
    .....
</body>
```

An example in the default Magento install can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: I added the htmlClass for <body> tag in the default.xml. then, i clear the cache but it not work for me.

Comment: @MikeZhang see my edit

Comment: Just a note on this functionality it is processed by `vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php::addBodyClass()` which strips out a lot of characters using regex and replaces them with `-` : 
`$className = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', strtolower($className));`

Comment: +1 @jzahedieh, i.e. adding 'page--blocks' comes out on frontend as 'page-blocks' , annoying :/

Comment: Also replaces underscores, why why why?!! :|

Comment: Is it possible to get that `value` from helper class? Not sure if it will allow to have `<arguments>`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to add a dynamic variable, eg. Store Code to the body class, you can take a look at the following example I made: https://github.com/samgranger/StoreCodeBodyClass